# Possible permutations of $3$ red and $3$ blue balls

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

if a bag contains n different color balls, then possible permutations are n!.

What if some of the balls have same color?
For example: If a bag contains 3 red balls & 3 blue balls and a person takes out the 6 balls by picking one ball at a time, then in how many possible ways 6 balls can be picked from bag?

I think the answer is 3x2x1 x 3x2x1 = 3! x 3! = 36

is it correct?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: As a way to think about it, you know how to do it if the balls were numbered, as in $(R_1,R_2,R_3,B_1,B_2,B_3)$.  Now you just need to note that permuting the $R_i$ or the $B_i$ doesn't change the selection.

Comment: You suggest $a! \times b!$ when $a$ balls are red and $b$ balls are blue. Check if your formula is correct with limit-case, for example $a=5$ and $b=1$, or even, $a=6$ and $b=0$.

Comment: The $3!^2$ should be the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you have still not been taught the formula for dealing with permutations of objects when some of them are identical.

You created permutations by multiplication, you can remove them by division, so if you have, say, $8$ objects where $5$ are $A's$ and $3$ are $B's$,

the formula will be $\Large\frac{8!}{5!3!}$

So can you apply the correct formula to your specific problem  ?

Read  more about it [here](https://byjus.com/permutation-formula/#:%7E:text=Permutation%20with%20repetition%3A%20This%20method,previous%20term%20for%20each%20time.)

Comment: The formula true blue anil is using is for [permutations of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Quite, but it seems to be more commonly known as permutations with repetition (of elements), eg at Brilliant.https://brilliant.org/wiki/permutations-with-repetition/

Comment: I have seen permutation with repetition used that way too.  The confusion about terminology is unfortunate.  A [permutation with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition) is a $k$-tuple of $n$ objects, of which there are $n^k$.